# Fixed hero top element not receiving pointer events

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a fixed top hero panel that the main content can scroll over and hide it:

```css
.root {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.hero span:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.scroll-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="fixed-top">
    <div class="hero">
      <span>Hover to turn yellow... Not working :-(</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-wrap">
    <main>
      Content...
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is my `scroll-wrap` element would prevent the underlying `hero` element to receive mouse events such as hover and click. My question is how to either split the mouse events such that the "transparent" part of the `scroll-wrap` would only receive scroll events, while forwarding all other events to the underlying div? Or is there a different arrangement of the whole thing that can produce what I'm trying to accomplish?

EDIT: the hover event is just an example. In reality, what I have is a bunch of buttons that I want the use to be able to click, with hover animation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `position:sticky` attribute on your .fixed-top element to fix it to the top of the div independently from the scroll (like position:fixed, but it works inside a div). You also need to set the `overflow:scroll` attribute to the container element :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}   

.root {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.hero span:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.scroll-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="fixed-top">
    <div class="hero">
      <span>Hover to turn yellow... Not working :-(</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-wrap">
    <main>
      Content...
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is becuase the `scroll-wrap` element goes on top of the `fixed-top` element and prevents it to fire the `hover` event. You can see it by inspecting in the `Elements` tab of the console.

To bypass it, you can change

```
.hero span:hover{...}
```

to

```
.root:hover .fixed-top .hero span {...}
```

But this way, **the events might not work as you want**. The `color` will change whenever you move your mouse over `root` element, not the `fixed-top` element. Therefore you might consider restructuring your elements.

Hope this helps.

```css
.root {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}



.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.root:hover .fixed-top .hero span {
  color: yellow;
}

.scroll-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="fixed-top">
    <div class="hero">
      <span>Hover to turn yellow... Not working :-(</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-wrap">
    <main>
      Content...
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please see my edit above. In reality, what I want is for the user to be able to click on the elements in the hero div. I don't think you solution will work in that case, although it's an interesting thought.